# Can't access my website, blocked by router or ISP?

Tags: ip, domain, cpanel

I was working on my website two days ago then was unable to access the cpanel. Then suddenly yesterday I was blocked completely.

I couldn't connect through ftp, cpanel login, domain name or ip address. I tried different computers and flushed dns cache.

I contacted my administrator and he said it was working fine. Then I tested on my iPhone and everything loaded fine. I then tested through proxy servers, some were successful at loading.

Is this a problem with my ISP or my router? How do I fix it if it's my router? The configuration options available on my router are super-basic to say the least, even with 'advanced settings' on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a problem with my ISP or my router?

Yes it is most likely a problem with either your ISP or with your router. It might also be a problem with your Computers but that is less likely, although you might have configured all of them the same way.

Using diagnostic tools such as `tracert` (Windows) or `traceroute` (Unix/Linux) will help you discover where the problem lies.

> How do I fix it if it's my router?

How you fix it depends on the make and model of router. I'm sure you'll get specific advice if you provide additional details of the equipment used, the operating system of your computers, the error messages displayed and the network details (does the router use DHCP to provide settings to the computers?)

Try traceroute then update your question with the results and additional details.

Comment: I thought I'd come back to this question to see if I can accept an answer. It turns out that the server was hypersensitive against attacks and was blocking me, maybe because I was creating too much traffic when I updated the content, regardless of which network I was on. I've since then switched. I remember trying the procedures you listed in your answer which helped me narrow it down to that.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing your DNS servers on your router to those of:

> **OpenDNS**
>
> 208.67.222.222
>
> 208.67.220.220
>
> ***or***
>
> **Google**
>
> 8.8.8.8
>
> 8.8.4.4

And then try browsing your site, this will allow you to know if your ISP is blocking you. Then simply call them and ask them to unblock your site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sites like [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) to find out whether it's a problem on your end.

Comment: Likewise, http://web-sniffer.net/ might be useful.

Comment: what exactly that is supposed to say or inform? I tried accessing it and it doesn't work on my side